# Building Driver for Intel X710-da2 on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, drivers, truenas, intel, compilation

I am trying to build the network driver for Intel X710-da2, which can be downloaded [here](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/14688/eng/ix-2.8.2.tar.gz) on FreeBSD 9.3.

I followed the Intel README but nevertheless I retrieve the following compile error after running the make command:

```
Warning: Object directory not changed from original /usr/home/miadmin/ix-2.8.2/src
cc -O2 -pipe -DSMP -DIXGBE_FDIR -DINET -DINET6 -DIXGBE_STANDALONE_BUILD -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror -D_KERNEL -DKLD_MODULE -nostdinc   -I. -I@ -I@/contrib/altq -finline-limit=8000 --param inline-unit-growth=100 --param large-function-growth=1000 -fno-common  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer  -mcmodel=kernel -mno-red-zone -mno-mmx -mno-sse -msoft-float  -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -std=iso9899:1999  -fstack-protector -Wall -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Winline -Wcast-qual  -Wundef -Wno-pointer-sign -fformat-extensions  -Wmissing-include-dirs -fdiagnostics-show-option   -c if_ix.c
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
if_ix.c:208: warning: redundant redeclaration of 'ixgbe_stop_mac_link_on_d3_82599' [-Wredundant-decls]
ixgbe_common.h:168: warning: previous declaration of 'ixgbe_stop_mac_link_on_d3_82599' was here
if_ix.c: In function 'ixgbe_setup_interface':
if_ix.c:2560: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
if_ix.c:2560: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
if_ix.c:2600: error: 'IFCAP_HWSTATS' undeclared (first use in this function)
if_ix.c:2600: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
if_ix.c:2600: error: for each function it appears in.)
*** [if_ix.o] Error code 1
```

What might be the problem for these errors?

My final goal is it to compile the driver in order to integrate it (later on, as described [here](http://blog.hani-ibrahim.de/en/netzwerktreiber-auf-freenas-installieren.html)) in my FreeNAS 9.3 environment since the integrated driver has issues ([Bug #9117](https://bugs.freenas.org/issues/9117)) with the X710-da2 network card.

Thank in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Seems some kernel headers are missing on your system (dev-setup), see: http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/if.h -- this is where "IFCAP_HWSTATS" is/should be defined: "head/sys/net/if.h" -- Did you install/download kernel headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inspecting version 9.x of the `if.h`file in different [versions of the FreeBSD kerne](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/if.h)l, "IFCAP_HWSTATS" was missing. In Version 10 it was present again, maybe FreeBSD developers have changed or broken this in version 9.x? As the latest driver by Intel in version **2.8.2** requires this declaration the compilation breaks - sadly.

For this reason, you should try with driver version **2.5.25**, as the driver description at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/83949/Intel-Ethernet-Converged-Network-Adapter-X710-Series states:

> This driver is intended for FreeBSD 7.2 or later

By contrast, the driver for driver 2.8.2 seems to be written for FreeBSD 10.x and upwards only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With this version of the driver, the build works under FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE-p30. Now I have to test this driver with my FreeNAS installation - hopefully this will work!